# Parse.cloud add validation on reset password

Tags: validation, parse-platform, passwords, parse-cloud-code

when we build some applications requires sign in and sign up, sometimes we must handle the "Forget Password" section and Parse.com provide it. but in default parse "forget password" doesn't include any validation when user inputting new password.

how to add validation to parse reset password on Parse Cloud Code? In this case i want to add uppercase, lowercase, and number validation.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse.com procedure for validating password requirements in Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771351/parse-com-procedure-for-validating-password-requirements-in-parse-cloud-beforesa)